# Elastic IP working with AWS EC2 instance, but Route 53 not resolving domain name

Tags: amazon-route53, elastic-ip

I transferred a domain from Godaddy some time ago.  I have created an EC2 instance with Elastic IP which works fine but it's not resolving the domain name.

The test in the AWS portal resolves the A record to the correct Elastic IP, but the name just gives:

```
...... server IP address could not be found.
Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
```

People have said that the DNS might still be with Godaddy, but I can't see the domain in my Godaddy account.

```
Dig gives A record
id 19510
opcode QUERY
rcode SERVFAIL
flags QR RD RA
;QUESTION
parlepal.com. IN A
;ANSWER
;AUTHORITY
;ADDITIONAL

and  NS
id 50166
opcode QUERY
rcode SERVFAIL
flags QR RD RA
;QUESTION
parlepal.com. IN NS
;ANSWER
;AUTHORITY
;ADDITIONAL
```

Any suggestions would be welcomed.

Comment: Has the domain name ever been functional on AWS? What is in the Route 53 console under "Registered Domains" and what is under "Hosted Zones"? Does the Hosted Zone for your domain contain an `NS` record?

Comment: I have never used the domain but it's been sat there in Route 53

There are NS records, but when I put them in a browser it says

Comment: I have never used the domain but it's been sat there in Route 53
Under registered domain there are 2 ns50.domaincontrol.com & ns49...

There are NS records under hosted zones, 
ns-1780.awsdns-30.co.uk.
ns-79.awsdns-09.com.
ns-1253.awsdns-28.org.
ns-1003.awsdns-61.net.

but when I put them in a browser it says This site cannot be reached

Comment: It sounds like you have different name servers defined in the two sections. They should be the same. See: [Linking Amazon Route 53 Domain Name to EC2 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33896045/174777)

Comment: Thank you John.  Do you know how it might have happened?

Comment: Thank you so much John.  I've update the record and it's working now.

Comment: It might be that they were created in the wrong order? Not sure, but glad to know you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

(Moving down from comment...)

A **Registered Domain** is associated with a number of **Name Servers**.

**Hosted Zones** have an `NS` record that defines the Name Servers to use with the Hosted Zone.

The Name Servers in both these sections **need to match** for the resolution process to work correctly.

See: [Linking Amazon Route 53 Domain Name to EC2 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33896045/174777)