# How to get Route53 to route to an S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-route53, static-site

I'm trying to configure Route53 to serve static content in an S3 bucket, but I cannot seem to get the configuration right (or it takes forever to work).

I followed several blogposts online and the AWS instructional materials to configure it, but it still doesn't direct anywhere.

I know the S3 buckets are configured correctly, because the S3 url shows my index.html.

However, I configured a hosted zone with an identical name, created an A record, selected the S3 bucket from a dropdown (it was generated by the site, so I know the names are correct) and when I try to hit the website with `curl` it errors, saying curl "could not resolve host".  I tried out the Route53 testing page, and get this response back

```
DNS response code
NOERROR
Protocol
UDP
Response returned by Route 53
52.218.240.139
```

I'm no expert, but it looks right to me.

Comment: Were these the steps you followed? [Configuring a Static Website Using a Custom Domain Registered with Route 53 - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html)

Comment: Yes.  Very similar directions are posted quite a few places online, and so it seemed like the right move.  As I said, the S3 stuff is all working fine, I can hit the url from the bucket and see the index.html, but I can't seem to get the domain I purchased to direct there, either in a browser or in curl.

Comment: I'd suggest breaking-down the problem to try and identify where things are going wrong. You could test the domain name by changing it to a normal A-Record (Alias=No) and put in an IP address like `1.2.3.4`. Wait a while for propagation, then try and resolve the DNS Name (eg vis nslookup or ping) and see whether it resolves to `1.2.3.4`. That will tell you whether the Route 53 configuration is working. If that is working, you can then try again with the bucket.

Comment: The route53 configuration is definitely not working. I grabbed an IP address from another site and nslookup fails with `server can't find <site>: SERVFAIL`

Comment: Excellent! So we now know that the problem seems to lie with the Route 53 setup rather than S3. First, I should ask... have you purchased a domain name? The bucket name should match the name of the domain you purchased. Within the Route 53 console, under "Registered Domains", your domain should appear with a name server configuration, which should match the setting in Hosted Zone. See: [Linking Amazon Route 53 Domain Name to EC2 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33896045/174777) Does all that match your setup?